# Change in duty cycle of a transistor (BJT)

Tags: transistors, high-frequency, high-speed

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN3Fzh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have recently been working on a project in which my requirement is to transmit the data through a transistor, at a typical speed of 100KHz to 200KHz.

While performing the experiment, I observed that the square wave with 50% duty cycle, which I generated from Arduino, at a frequency of 158KHz, changed the duty cycle to 42%.

The transistor I used was 2N2222, whose dynamic characteristics according to the datasheet is in the range of hundreds of megahertz.

Does anyone have a idea about the cause of the anomaly?

Comment: We need to see your entire circuit in schematic form. My guess is that you have used a pullup resistor and the RC time constant of your circuit is causing slow rise time.

Comment: What characteristic? The current-gain-bandwidth product (which is not the same as the bandwidth)?

Comment: Is this a 5 V Arduino?

Comment: Somewhere downstream from the Arduino, in a part of the circuit you haven't shown us, the circuit is turning on slower than it is turning off - reducing the duty cycle.

Comment: At 200 kHz and above, you'll normally see this problem with your topology. You need to modify the circuit in one of several ways to get closer to the driving duty cycle. Prevent saturation, use common base, use active sink and source with customized speed ups, etc. How close to 50% do you need to be?

Comment: One another observation I found is that till the frequency of 15kHz, the system is working fine. As I move to higher frequencies, the duty cycle keeps on reducing.

Comment: @CL.Yes. It is a 5V arduino.

Comment: Duty Cycle till the base of the transistor is perfectly 50%. At the collector of the transistor, it reduces to a lower value.

Comment: A bipolar driven into "saturation" mode has lots of charge stored in the forward-biased collector-base junction. To turn OFF the transistor requires time to sweep out that charge. A 100pF capacitor across the base resistor will speed-up that charge removal.

Comment: *As I move to higher frequencies, the duty cycle keeps on reducing* That's a clear sign that you have a delay in the circuit. You will need to use an oscilloscope to determine what is happening.

Comment: Even if you had the proper duty cycle and frequency driving the LED, I doubt that a white LED can blink that fast.  White LEDs are typically blue LEDs with a phosphor that glows white when excited by the blue light.  It takes a bit of time for the glow to start, then it takes a bit of time for the glow to stop.  If you switch too fast, the phosphor can't follow.  No light, or constant light.  Check the datasheet of your LED to see how fast it can light up and extinguish.

Comment: Are you seeing the reduced duty cycle in the transistor, or in the received signal?  (Whatever is supposed to detect your 100kHz light pulses.)

Comment: @JRE, duty cycle is reduced in the transistor.

Comment: @JRE, I tried removing the LED and placing just a resistor as a load, but the result is same, Reduced duty cycle.

Comment: Yeah.  The effect I was talking about is in the emitted light pulses.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf According to your point, if the turn off speed is reduced, then the duty cycle of the signal should increase, but the situation is opposite.

Comment: @JRE according to my research and experience, the phosphors used in white LEDs have very little persistence. The number is almost never given in the datasheet because most people don't care. If there is significant persistence you'd see a change in color temperature with frequency (easy test).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was about to write about the same. Current LEDs don't use real phosporus (chemical element P).

Comment: @JimmyB The [phosphors](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor)  used in white LEDs are rare-earth compounds such as Cerium-doped Yttrium- Aluminium-Garnet (YAG), which emits yellow light. Warm white LEDs add some red emitting phosphor which typically has something like Europium.

Answer (score 2):

Compare your circuit with a non-saturating version:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRT87Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]

You may have to add some resistance in series with the LED to keep the transistor power dissipation low enough to use a small transistor.

The cause of the slower turn-off than turn-on is saturation of the BJT. As you can see the duty cycle (in terms of current) is higher than the input duty cycle. Since LED current is what generates the light, that means you're getting more light than would be expected from the PWM duty cycle.

Another way of preventing saturation is to use a **small** (low capacitance) Schottky diode from collector to base. That is a version of the classic [Baker Clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_clamp).